# Create PDF preview from multiple eps/ai files

Tags: macos, software-rec

I am looking for software under OSX if possible, to be able to create PDF preview out of many eps files. It should take eps files as input(or perhaps scan dirs) and give output PDF.
Hope there is such tool...

I can do it with AI, but I am looking for something to automate this, because I have way too many eps files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Preview to the rescue!

1. Select all the eps files in the Finder.
2. Right click, and Open With Preview
3. View->Thumbnails to make sure the sidebar is open
4. Click on one of the thumbnails and Cmd-A to select all of them.
5. Drag them into the first thumbnail.  This will copy the contents of all the items into additional pages in the first.
6. File->Save... And give it a new name.

Next option. If you have Illustrator, you have Adobe Bridge.

1. Select all the EPS files in Adobe Bridge.
2. Click the Output button near the top right of bridge.
3. Select PDF (on by default for me)
4. Select the layout you want.
5. Select save.

Final option. I used to use TeX to do this:

```
#!/bin/sh

cat > sample.tex <<EOF
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[margin=.50in]{geometry}
%% Some useful definitions...

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{5}
EOF

ls *.eps | awk '{ printf "\\noindent\\includegraphics[width=\\linewidth]{%s}\\par\\noindent\\nobreak\\verb+%s+\\par\\par\n", $1, $1 }' >> sample.tex

cat >> sample.tex <<EOF
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
EOF

latex sample.tex
dvips sample.dvi -o
rm sample.tex sample.dvi sample.aux sample.log
```

Comment: Latex option did the trick, so just need to polish script little - sometimes file name of the last thumbnail in the page goes to next column thus creating mess. Is there any way to prevent this or maybe put file name on top of thumbnail? Thanks a lot!